# ping bot in ASP.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a small project I am trying to wrap my head around. I already have the UI and the database built and working.

The app should ping a list of IP addresses every x seconds, and then update the UI if the address is up or down. What is the best way to go about executing this and updating my ui?

Comment: You have several options, for ex. running windows service (robot) who loops and pings and writes the results to db from where your front reads results. Or your front calls every second the back api method, who pings and gets result.

Comment: I would prefer to have everything done via asp.net and not need a windows service. I was looking into hang fire as an option

Comment: Infinite javascript loop?  You could put a "start" and "stop" button somewhere on the page but basically it fires an ajax request and in the controller you make process the ping etc, then return whatever as json and update the display.  I've done something kinda like this as part of a very long running calculation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend two approaches.

- Using JavaScript and AJAX: You can periodically execute a client side function to call a server side function to ping the list of IPs and update the UI.
- Using Signal R: This is a framework suitable for real time web apps. So in your case it does make sense.

Refer- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr